# libcurl verion 7.45.0 rtsp with digest authentication

Tags: curl, rtsp

I saw the curl's change log for 7.45.0 from website.

It said that bug for rtsp: support basic/digest authentication was fixed.

But it doesn't tell how to use the digest authentication for rtsp.

I sent the describe message to rtsp server , and it returned RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized... message log.

Therefore do u guys know how to send account/passwd/digest to rtsp server ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you mean libcUrl this way worked for me with spook rtsp/rtp server (Edimax flavour):

```
curl_easy_setopt(csession, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_easy_setopt(csession, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
```